# How to ping a webservice like svc, asmx

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, sockets

I have .net application and I want to ping some webservices and show the status on a webpage.
I tried ping but i am getting "No such host in known".

But the ping works for a url or ip but not working for a service.

Please put ideas here

UPDATE:

I used HttpWebResponse and request. I am getting 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Cold you include more details and samples

Answer (score 3):

Use a [head HTTP verb](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) to check. "This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification."

Comment: Its not reaching that part. I getting 401 exception before that

Comment: Try this to authenticate your request before sending it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2004/07/28/199706.aspx

Comment: let me try it. This deals with HttpWebRequest and response. Why will not Ping work in this case?

Comment: My understanding is ping works at the hostname and ip address level "Allows an application to determine whether a remote computer is accessible over the network." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx and you want to know if a specific url is working.

Comment: Is getting error 404 enough to be sure that specific uri doesn't exist? Or should I check some another error codes for that?

Comment: Responses in the 500 range mean something is wrong with the server. Here is a full listing of valid responses: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 1):

What are you pinging?  If you want to check to see if a webservice is there, then just navigate to the full URL of the service and see if you get a page not found or not.  In a webpage, you could even get fancy and check it using an ajax request (look up Microsoft.XMLHTTP)
Funny you should ask this because every webservice I have developed, the first method I add to it is ping :) which returns it's state in a one liner that can be displayed on a form.

Comment: Can you please explain me how you used ping in this case?

Comment: No , you can't use ping.  Ping is a specif type of protocol that just send a message to a port that knows how to respond to the echo request protocol.  You have to use http to talk to a webserver.  You can also talk to webservers using telnet if you type in the http request to tell it which page you want to get

Comment: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php check that out.  Careful that the service doesn't log when you touch it or the server admin will complaint that you are filling his logs with junk.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to ping the Web Service address instead of the entire End Point? Basically an EndPoint is composed by an Address an a location.Let's suppose you have the following Web Service called CustomerService.svc.

```
http://myserver.somedomain.com/services/CustomerService.svc
```

You should try the ping to the address which is myserver.somedomain.com.Also you should consider that some servers have the ping command disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an application such as [WCF Storm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx) or [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) that will act as a client to your WCF service. Both have free versions, I believe. They will let you construct an XML request to test the service.

Also, I like to put an actual Ping method in my services that receives an `int` and returns a string with the same `int` and a timestamp. It's not strictly necessary, but it helps as a sanity check in a pinch.

Comment: I want it for my application no third party tools